# Danish keyboards in WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm

I have heard a lot of good stuff about WebStorm. So I have decided to give it a chance over Visual Studio Code. However first thing I discover is that my Danish keyboard does not work with the shortcuts provided by the user interface. I have seen some posts about keymap file, and providing your own key codes.

Isn't there any standard way to get it working with a Danish keyboard? I must be missing something here can't be right you have to map your keyboard to get a product working:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue unfortunately. The problem is that Java returns incorrect key codes unless US keyboard layout is chosen.
We are working on patching OpenJDK to fix the issue, please follow [JBR-216](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-216) for updates

Comment: WOW 12 year old bug and not fixed? I am really surpriced that this people suggested this over the the free Visual Studio Code. When shortcuts dosent work :/ But thanks for your reply appreciated.

Comment: Sad. I switch back to the free Visual Studio Code :( They dont depend on those kind of software.